# Create single CSV from two CSV files with X and Y values in python

Tags: python, list, csv, geo

I have two CSV files; one containing X(longitude) and the other Y(latitude) values (they are 'float' data type)

I am trying to create a single CSV with all possible combinations (e.g. X1,Y1; X1, Y2; X1,Y3; X2,Y1; X2,Y2; X2,Y3... etc)

I have written the following which partly works. However the CSV file created has lines in between values and i also get the values stored like this with there list parentheses ['20.7599'] ['135.9028']. What I need is 20.7599, 135.9028

```
import csv

inLatCSV = r"C:\data\Lat.csv"
inLongCSV = r"C:\data\Long.csv"
outCSV = r"C:\data\LatLong.csv"

with open(inLatCSV, 'r') as f:
  reader = csv.reader(f)
  list_Lat = list(reader)

with open(inLongCSV, 'r') as f:
   reader = csv.reader(f)
   list_Long = list(reader)

with open(outCSV, 'w') as myfile:
   for y in list_Lat:
       for x in list_Long:
            combVal = (y,x)
            #print (combVal)
            wr = csv.writer(myfile)
            wr.writerow(combVal)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a argument to the `open` function made the difference:

```
with open(my_csv, 'w', newline="") as myfile:
    combinations = [[y,x] for y in list_Lat for x in list_Long]
    wr = csv.writer(myfile)
    wr.writerows(combinations)
```

Answer (score 1):

Any time you're doing something with csv files, [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) is a great tool

```
import pandas as pd

lats = pd.read_csv("C:\data\Lat.csv",header=None)
lons = pd.read_csv("C:\data\Long.csv",header=None)

lats['_tmp'] = 1
lons['_tmp'] = 1

df = pd.merge(lats,lons,on='_tmp').drop('_tmp',axis=1)
df.to_csv('C:\data\LatLong.csv',header=False,index=False)
```

We create a dataframe for each file, and merge them on a temporary column, which produces the cartesian product. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.20/merging.html